# ElasticSearch: search results is different per node?

Tags: search, elasticsearch

Imagine a test cluster with **2** nodes on a single server with ElasticSearch 0.90.6 on board.

Lets create test index `tindex`:

```js
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/tindex -d '{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 8,
            "number_of_replicas" : 1
        }
    }
}'
```

and test type `ttype`, insert some data (10000 queries / rows for example) into, with mapping like:

```js
{"title": "...", "description": "..."}
```

When I do a search query to find `foo`:

```js
curl -X POST localhost:9200/tindex/ttype/_search?pretty -d '{
    "min_score": 0.01,
    "query":
    {
        "common":
        {
            "_all":
            {
                "query": "foo",
                "cutoff_frequency": 0.001
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight":
    {
        "pre_tags": ["<b>"],
        "post_tags": ["</b>"],
        "fields":
        {
            "title":
            {},
            "description":
            {}
        }
    },
    "suggest":
    {
        "text": "foo",
        "results":
        {
            "phrase":
            {
                "field": "title",
                "size": 5,
                "confidence": 0.01,
                "highlight":
                {
                    "pre_tag": "<b>",
                    "post_tag": "</b>"
                }
            }
        },
        "results1":
        {
            "phrase":
            {
                "field": "description",
                "size": 5,
                "confidence": 0.01,
                "highlight":
                {
                    "pre_tag": "<b>",
                    "post_tag": "</b>"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Each time I have different odd and even results, as I realized then, they is different per each node. This is **solved** by nodes restart. Also I was tried to clear cache via _cache API, no sense.

Is there a better solution to solve this inconsistency in realtime?

Comment: What you saw is not a normal issue, especially if it was solved by node restart. I think the nodes had issues communicating with each other and you had a split brain.

Comment: @javanna Is there any option to put data **force** synchronously?